# How do I merge two ext4 partitions?

Tags: partitioning, gparted

So I have two partitions, an 80 GB Partition (where I installed Ubuntu on) and a 44 GB partition (With nothing on it), Both are ext4 partitions.

How do I merge them into one without losing my data?

Comment: From the image you put up, I can't see the full layout of your /dev/sda. Please post another image of /dev/sda without the other move/resize window in front, then I can make a better recommendation. From what I CAN see, the 44GB partition may not be immediately next to the 80GB partition, and that's why you can't resize. (You may end up with doing a backup for safety, a move, and a resize). Cheers, Al

Comment: I see TWELVE partitions in your picture, not 2. Could you please be more accurate when asking questions?

Comment: http://prnt.sc/cza6t9 one is an EFI partition, one is the partition where windows is saved on.  I formatted the 41 GiB (44 GB) partition to ext4, its the partition thats highlighted. Sorry if I wasnt accurate enough with my question. SDA5 is where Ubuntu is stored, SDA10 is the partition I want to merge with SDA5.

Comment: See my answer. Cheers, Al

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, here we go...

**FIRST, do a backup of sda5!**

Boot to the Ubuntu Live DVD and start gparted.

1. right-click on sda9 and issue a swapoff
2. right-click on sda10 and delete it
3. right-click on sda9 and issue a move/resize
4. place the pointer in the center of the partition, it'll change to a hand icon, and MOVE the partition all the way left
5. click the APPLY icon
6. right-click on sda9 and issue a swapon
7. right-click on sda5 and issue a move/resize
8. MOVE the partition all the way left, the same way as you did before
9. RESIZE sda5 by dragging the RIGHT-SIDE-HANDLE all the way to the right
10. click the APPLY icon
11. reboot the computer

Comment: This worked! Thank you very much! I I selected the question as "Answered". Have a nice day!

Comment: Glad it worked out ok for you! Cheers, Al

Answer (score 1):

Start up a live session from the Ubuntu installation medium or burn a gparted live dvd and boot from it. (install and) start gparted.

In gparted execute the following 2 tasks ...

- Delete the 44Gb partition;
- Enlarge the 80Gb partition with the unallocated 44Gb.

Comment: So i attempted to do this, i cant resize the 80 gb partition, 44 gb partition is unallocated. Picture: http://m.imgur.com/w9p9LPv

Comment: You assume that the 44GB partition is immediately next to the 80GB partition, and that **may** not be the exact case. I've asked the OP for a plain gparted screenshot, without the move/resize window in front. Cheers, Al ps: I never resize left, always a move and a resize right.

Comment: "So I have two partitions" How can 2 partitions NOT be next to eachother? He got the answer that was to be expected from what he asked. Sorry, not my mistake.

Comment: When there's a swap partition in between. Giggle. See my answer. Cheers, Al

Comment: That makes it 3 partition. ;-)

Comment: Cannot move the partition back when the empty unallocated space is right before it.